# WorkSheet Change - Matches_Target/Intersect

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, events, filter

What works: Code scans `column E` for matches on Sheet1. Copy/pastes rows to Sheet2 if matches are found.

1st Issue: Sheet1 is dynamic and each new match added will recopy old matches it already copied before.

2nd Issue: Worksheet Change event is scanning entire Sheet1 for changes. Goal is event scans `column E` only for changes that equal `Match` triggering the copy/paste part of the code.

[image]

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Worksheets("Sheet2").ToggleButton1.Value = True Then

Application.EnableEvents = False

If Intersect(Target, Sheet1.Range("E:E")) Is Nothing Then GoTo 
ResetEvents

If Target.Address = "E:E" And Target.Value = "Match" Then

a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To a
    If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 5).Value = "Match" Then
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
Next

ResetEvents:
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe only update the row of the cell that triggered the event if needed

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking. It would work. I think I am using my `Target` wrong in my `WorkSheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)` event? Is it not set properly?

Comment: The target is automatically get the active cell that is selected when the worksheet is changed, so to focus on column E, you should set the target to column E. I.e: If target.address like "asterisk symbol E asterisk symbol" (sorry but I dont know why the asterisk symbol is not shown)

Comment: And you should add some code to check if the cell being copied from Company worksheet is already existed or not in Matches worksheet

Comment: I am working on your first comment as that is what I suspected. Your second comment is tricky for me.

Comment: Re _The target is automatically get the active cell that is selected_ no, that's not correct.  `Target` references the cell or cells that changed, which may or may not also be selected.

Comment: Oh well that might change everything then. Should I consider another event? `Worksheet_Calculate` I am not using the `Intersect` feature. Will using both `Target` and `Intersect` help?

Comment: Do you think this kind of process work for you ? each time any cell with value in column E is changed : (1). clear all cells in sheet2 completely. 2. In Sheet1, filter column E with "match" criteria 3. copy the visible cells in sheet1 (4) paste to sheet2. With this kind of code, it doesn't need to check if the cell value is changed to "match" or "ignore".

Comment: Another way is a bit complicated. Set a range variable to try to find the ID of target row in sheet 2. Example : `set c = sheet2.columns(1).find(target.offset(0,-4).value, lookat:=xlwhole)`. Make a case for the target value. `select case target.value` ... `case "match": if c is nothing then target.row.copy Destination:=sheet2.range("A2").end(xldown).offset(1,0)`. In the case target value "match" and if the ID is not found (so, c is nothing), then copy the target row and put it to the next available cell in sheet2.  `case "ignore" : if not c is nothing then c.entirerow.delete`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your first suggestion I tried originally. It worked however as the data is coming in dynamically to Sheet1 if Sheet1 is filtered the data does not fill in properly because the sheet is filtered. So, I abandoned the filtering logic.